# How can I select all rows based on the AVG calculated in another column?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select all the rows where the symbol meets the condition that AVG on column "volume" is greater than 100000.
Something like -

`SELECT * FROM etf_daily WHERE symbol, avg(volume)>1000000  GROUP BY symbol`

I have this table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DS6p.jpg)

Comment: Use a HAVING clause for set function conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation and a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT symbol, avg(volume)
FROM etf_daily 
GROUP BY symbol
HAVING AVG(volume) > 1000000 ;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, use window functions:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (SELECT d.*, 
             AVG(volume) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol) as symbol_avg
      FROM etf_daily d
     ) d
WHERE symbol_avg > 1000000 ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the command selects only one line for the entire symbol group. The goal is to count AVG for each symbol and if the result meets the condition> 100000, all lines of the symbol (s) are selected.